# Netgear FSM726A Reset to Factory Defaults

Tags: switch, netgear

I have a Netgear FSM726A v2 switch, there are several vlans already configured, and I need to reset to get all the traffic in the same vlan.

I do not have a console cable or telnet access. I tried switching it off and on, pressed the reset button for a while, but nothing changed. I hope there's some way to do a hardware reset.

I do not need to keep the current configuration, I'd rather reset it to the factory defaults. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the manual doesn't actually cover much more than how to plug the unit in, it doesn't say how to reset the switch to factory defaults. The reset button does nothing but reboot the switch, just like unplugging and plugging back in.

To reset the password you need a console cable:

1. Plug it in, fire up your favorite terminal software.
2. Reboot the switch, during boot mash the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key.
3. If prompted what to boot from, select Flash, and continue with previous step.
4. When you get the ">" prompt, enter "EmergencyPasswordReset"
5. It'll ask if you're sure, follow the prompts.

This will only reset the password (blank password). That'll get your into the configuration where you can change things to however you like.

On a side note: Most network guys avoid Netgear like the plague because of BS like this. Their equipment is very difficult to configure, uses odd semantics, is completely unintuitive, very poorly documented, and their phone support is just as bad. In the future get ProCurve, Cisco, or even PowerConnect switches.

Answer (score 6):

[HERE](http://kbserver.netgear.com/pdf/fsm726v2_install_guide.pdf)'s the manual, there appears to be a section on how to do just that.

Comment: actually the manual says that 'The reset will not change any of the switch's configuration, nor will it
save any changes to the configuration.'... I guess those in NETGEAR don't wanna this feature on.. thanks on the manual...

Comment: In the other manual it describes how to do a "Tools> Restore Factory Defaults"; http://www.manualowl.com/p/Netgear/FSM726v2/Manual/61146 - these were very easy to find by the way, first page of google search for "FSM726A manual", this site is for professional IT people, who normally come here once they've covered the basics.

Comment: @Chopper3, that assumes she knows the password to the device. If not, the manuals don't say how to reset the password. She didn't say if she knew the password or not however.

Comment: thanks for the manuals @chopper3 ,, but actually i wanted a way to do a hardware reset, without the need to login via a console or telnet.. and it seems like none of those manuals describes such thing...

Comment: @AMY, if you know the password, the WebGUI is the easiest by far.

Comment: @Chris i actually don't know the password... i'll try to get it.. though i thought there must be some hardware way like the 30 seconds reset button... seems like those netgear people didn't implement that...

Comment: No, may have to take the cover off and have a poke around, maybe call their support too

Comment: am in a very far country and i believe they didn't hear about it, so i don't think they'll have a support line... i'll maybe get a rollover cable and 'take the cover off and have a poke around' as you said... the problem is that i don't need that mess-around because i need the switch for a very basic function so I thought they would've implemented a quick reset function... I guess I should stop complaining and get that thing done.. thank you both for your patience :)

Answer (score 1):

Chopper3's link to manual not working for me (error 404)
Theres some backup link for other users http://www.manualsworld.net/manual/378508/netgear/fsm726

Comment: manual does not help in that specific situation, but thank you..